# Android Studio not recognizing base packages such as String or Integer 'Cannot Resolve Symbol ...'

Tags: java, android, package

My Android Studio no longer recognizes basic embedded packages such as Strings and Integers.

This is something that occurs across any projects so it may not have to do with code.

I have tried looking into the JDK however nothing has changed with it and it used to work okay in the past. I have also tried Invalidate and Restart which is the most used tool for miscellaneous issues.

Seems like the Java kit is misplaced because this is for all basic types String, Integers, Objects...

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open up Android Studio to the welcome screen where you can select projects
2. Click on `Configure` in the lower right corner
3. Click on `Project Defaults` and then click on `Project Structure`
4. Click on the checkbox `Use Embedded JDK (Recommended)`
5. Click `OK`

That will use the Android Studio embedded JDK instead of a configured one.